# Quickest way to toggle between apps (Alt-Tab equivalent) *not* requiring 3rd-party apps?

Tags: user-interface

There seem to be a handful of apps with this functionality in mind, but I'd prefer an inbuilt solution. (I'm on the S4 mini)

---

See also [here](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/505701-best-if-i-can-say-so-alt-tab-android.html).

Answer (score 4):

There is one way not requiring third-party apps: long-pressing the home button.

Comment: Yes, 've come across that one. This is currently the best way I know of, but it's not very quick...

Comment: In fact, this is *not* a real "toggle", but rather a (potential) shortcut to (slightly) expedite slowly tapping your way from one app to the next (and back again).

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty I'm afraid I don't see the difference. What do you count as a "toggle" other than switching from one to the next?

Comment: Instant switching. (Like in Windows and Linux Alt-Tab or Linux workspace switching.) I'm trying to speed things up on my S4: maybe this will also help speed up your suggestion: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55060/how-to-disable-shortcut-to-launch-samsungs-s-voice-without-accepting-its-to

Comment: If you use a phone with a dedicated task switching button (like the Nexus 4) it's way faster. Takes about 0.5s there.

Comment: I believe what @nutty wants is a way to instantly switch to another app that he wants without viewing the multitasking menu/screen. I also think that Dan's answer is the best answer to the question, since there's no real way to do that without an app or modification.