# How to disable shortcut to launch (Samsung's) S Voice *without* accepting its ToS?

Tags: s-voice

> [By default, when you double-tap the home key, you'll launch straight into S Voice.](http://www.androidcentral.com/galaxy-s4-quick-tip-disable-s-voice-shortcut-faster-home-button-response)

To disable that shortcut, one could

> load S Voice, then press the menu key and hit "Settings." Next,
>   uncheck "Open via the home key." That's it -- with the shortcut combo
>   disabled, the home button should respond immediately as opposed to
>   with a very slight delay.

However, this method seems viable only once Samsung's Terms of Service (ToS) have been accepted - only after which S Voice will launch fully. Any way to disable that key combo *without* having to accept ToS of a S I do not want?

<sub>Note that at this stage I do *not* (yet) want to uninstall S Voice. If you happen to know *how* to uninstall it, I'd appreciate a comment, though :-)</sub>

Answer (score 5):

I just disabled S Voice entirely for now, [as explained here](http://www.conanhughes.com/2013/07/remove-android-bloatware-how-to.html) and elsewhere:

`Application Manager >> All >> S Voice >> Disable`, then reboot.